# Prune mysql table - averaging records

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a MySQL table which stores real-time data from different devices. Data is recorded about every 20 seconds.
The table looks like this:

```
report_dt             device    value1    value2
2015-10-16 10:32:15   solar     34.4      67.8
2015-10-16 10:32:15   grid      56.9      23.5
2015-10-16 10:32:35   solar     45.6      34.3
```

Queries to get the recorded values per device are pretty CPU consuming. I have (report_dt,device) as primary key. Besides, after a few days I do not need the 20 second data anymore, but just the 10 minute average.

So either the same table setup or a table per device would be satisfactory, with this contents:

```
report_dt             device    value1    
2015-10-16 10:00:00   solar     avg(value1 over 10 mins)
2015-10-16 10:10:10   grid      avg(value1 over 10 mins)
2015-10-16 10:20:20   solar     avg(value1 over 10 mins)
```

The idea is to run the pruning action once every 24 hours.

The reason is that data containing averages must be retrieved fast. And because the data in a 20 second interval is extremely fluctuating, I must use averaging or the data is difficult to assess.

I could do this in an application. Retrieve the average values for 10 minutes at each 10 minute interval and write it back to a different table or different tables, one for each device.

But would something also be possible with a database function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by [Events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)  in mysql. Suppose i have 2 `tables` in mysql. Table_1 store the data continiously per second or miunte as your application generate. Table_2 is your main table which contains the 10 min `avg` data. Now you need to create a stored procedure which calls once in 10 minutes (this can be done by Events or  [CRON in linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps) ).  So whats contains the `stored procedure` ? These steps perform in Stored Procedure

```
BEGIN
   SELECT  avg(value) of last 10 min from Table_1
   INSERT into Table_2 the avg record.
   DELETE avg(value) of last 10 min from Table_1
END
```

*Caution- I am not developing mysql code, i am just show the approach*

Comment: How could I forgot about stored procedures? It is the correct answer of course and the principle is correct. However with a few more lines (check if the destination table exists, calculate the time interval) it becomes almost impossible to enter, alter and debug the code. MySQL does not provide any easy way to do it. So although this is the most elegant solution, I reverted to an external bash script, calling mysql client.